# Instead of many event listeners and functions referring to one object what is a better way?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a better way to write this rather than write four functions that do essentially the same thing? How could I call the same function but display different properties of the same object using that function.

In the following example, `a` is a "paragraph" element.
The event listeners are tied to "input" elements the type is button.

```
function $(id){
    return document.querySelector(id);
};

function Person(name, age, weight, favoriteActivity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.favoriteActivity = favoriteActivity;
}

var Jack = new Person("Jack Crish", 29, 200, "coding");

var a = document.querySelector("#person");

function showAge(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.age;
}
function showName(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.name;
}
function showWeight(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.weight;
}
function showActivity(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.favoriteActivity;    
}

$("#age").addEventListener("click", showAge);
$("#name").addEventListener("click", showName);
$("#weight").addEventListener("click", showWeight);
$("#enjoys").addEventListener("click", showActivity);
```

JSFiddle found here: http://jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/

Comment: maybe, a showProperty method that accepts a parameter specifying what property to display? ....

Comment: In the constructor object right.
Something like:

   this.showInfo = function(this.??){}

Comment: I love the variety of responses this question is getting.  I should tuck this away and use it as an interview question.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just have the function accept a parameter that dictates what property to show.

```js
function $(id){
    return document.querySelector(id);
};

function Person(name, age, weight, favoriteActivity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.favoriteActivity = favoriteActivity;
}

var Jack = new Person("Jack Crish", 29, 200, "coding");

var a = $("#person");

function showProperty(property) {
    this.innerHTML = Jack[property];
}

/*
function showAge(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.age;
}
function showName(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.name;
}
function showWeight(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.weight;
}
function showActivity(){
    a.innerHTML = Jack.favoriteActivity;    
}
*/

$("#age").addEventListener("click", showProperty.bind(a, 'age'));
$("#name").addEventListener("click", showProperty.bind(a, 'name'));
$("#weight").addEventListener("click", showProperty.bind(a, 'weight'));
$("#enjoys").addEventListener("click", showProperty.bind(a, 'favoriteActivity'));
```

```css
p{
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<p id ="person"></p>
<input id ="age" type = "button" value = "age"></input> 
<input id ="name" type = "button" value = "name"></input> 
<input id ="weight" type = "button" value = "weight"></input> 
<input id ="enjoys" type = "button" value = "enjoys"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since object properties are accessible as string indexes, and based on the fact that your element's ids are exactly the properties names, you could use the event caller's id reference as the property to be changed:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/3/)

```
function show() {
    a.innerHTML = Jack[this.id];
}

$("#age").addEventListener("click", show);
$("#name").addEventListener("click", show);
$("#weight").addEventListener("click", show);
$("#enjoys").addEventListener("click", show);
```

**EDIT**

As pointed by Kevin B, you would need them to match the *enjoys* id, to the actual property name, like:

http://jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/4/

```
<input id ="favoriteActivity" type = "button" value = "enjoys"></input> 

$("#favoriteActivity").addEventListener("click", show);
```

Comment: all except enjoys of course, though i like this solution better.

Comment: Seems like this could be shortened again? `$("#age,#name,#weight,#enjoys").addEventListener("click", show);`

Comment: That's a pretty slick answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are, but they're also worse. For instance:

```
function Person(...) { ...; this.setup(); };

Person.prototype = {
  setup: function() {
    var self = this;
    ['name','age','weight','activity'].forEach(function(propName) {
      var fname = "show"+propName;
      self[fname] = function() { return self[propName]; }
      document.getElementById(propName).addEventListener("click", self[fname]);
    });
  }
};
```

Is it better? Well, yes and no. It's more concice, there's less code that can go wrong because it's not duplicated, but now you have a hardcoded list of properties that you need to update, and your object's API is about as transparent as mud (you now have to analyse the code to find out what functions your Person object has).

The best practice is to make your objects transparent, with an easy to read API:

```
function Person(name, age, weight, favoriteActivity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.favoriteActivity = favoriteActivity;
}

Person.prototype = {
  showAge: function(evt){
    evt.target.textContent = this.age;
  },
  showName: function(evt){
    evt.target.textContent = this.name;
  },
  showWeight: function(evt){
    evt.target.textContent = this.weight;
  },
  showActivity: function(evt){
    evt.target.textContent = this.favoriteActivity;
  },
  bindToElement: function(a){
    a.querySelector(".name").addEventListener("click", this.showAge);
    a.querySelector(".age").addEventListener("click", this.showName);
    a.querySelector(".weight").addEventListener("click", this.showWeight);
    a.querySelector(".fav").addEventListener("click", this.showActivity);
  }
};
```

and then have some separate code for initialising Persons:

```
function makePerson(name) {
  var person = new Person(name);
  var el = document.querySelector("....");
  person.bindToElement(el);
}

...

makePerson("Jack");
```

And try to stay way from those `id` selectors. They're a great way to make sure you can't ever add another thing to your page.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can access properties of an object both through the format of `Jack.name` but also by `Jack['name']`. So if all you're doing in each function is accessing a property of a given object, you could create one function called, say, `showInfo`, that takes the name of the property you want to access:

```
function showInfo(field) {
    a.innerHtml = Jack[field];
}
```

With that, calling `showInfo('name')` would be the same as calling showName(). You could then have each listener pass in a string to the same function - possibly even determining those strings based on the IDs of the button. Hopefully that points you in the direction of better reducing your code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "get" method to your Person.prototype

```
Person.prototype.get = function (p) {
    a.innerHTML = this[p]; 
}
```

and call it in your eventListener

```
$("input").addEventListener("click", function() {Jack.get(this.value);});
$("#name").addEventListener("click", function() {Jack.get(this.value);});
$("#weight").addEventListener("click", function() {Jack.get(this.value);});
$("#enjoys").addEventListener("click", function() {Jack.get(this.value);});
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g97p2qta/).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that does your event binding, and specifies which property at once:

```
function showProperty(id, property) {
    $("#" + id).addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        a.innerHTML = Jack[property];
    });
}

showProperty("age", "age");
showProperty("name", "name");
showProperty("weight", "weight");
showProperty("enjoys", "favoriteActivity");
```

[jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/2/)

Or, you could take a more declarative approach, and infer the property from the button.  This would require adding an attribute to the `enjoys` button:

```
<input type="button" value="enjoys" data-property="favoriteActivity" />
```

```
function showProperty(e) {
    var property = this.getAttribute("data-property") || this.value;
    a.innerHTML = Jack[property];
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", showProperty);
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/metkjnyn/5/)

Both are more DRY than your original.

Comment: Appreciate the insights. Thank you.